# BlogEngine.NET Server time offset

Tags: asp.net, blogs, blogengine.net

I am using **BlogEngine.NET 2.5.0.6** and at `Settings > Basic` I find an option `Server time offset` that is used to change the "blog time" regarding the server time. The problem is I can't add '+' character. And I didn't find a way to add positive hours. When I add numbers to that option it only diminishes from the server time. I need to add 6h to the server time. Is that even possible? If not possible using the GUI, is there any code tweak that could be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if adding normal numbers (positive) subtracts, you should try adding negative numbers to go the opposite direction. The "+" is not a valid character when dealing with integers (simply the absence of a minus sign would indicate positive).

Comment: Perfect... didn't even try that. Thanks.